# Fseek on C problem

Tags: c

I'm testing this code, but doesn't work, it always says that an error occurred :S

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *file_pointer;
    file_pointer = fopen("text.txt","r");
    if(fseek(file_pointer, 0, -1)) {
        puts("An error occurred");
    }
    else {
        char buffer[100];
        fgets(buffer, 100, file_pointer);
        puts("The first line of the file is:");
        puts(buffer);
    }
    fclose(file_pointer);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked that the file opened correctly?
ie if file_pointer is null?

Typical C usage would be something like

```
FILE *file_pointer;
if ( !(file_pointer=fopen("text.txt","r")) ) {
    puts("Error opening file");
    puts(strerror(errno)); /* prints the system error message */
    return 1; /* returning non-zero exits the program as failed */
}

if(fseek(file_pointer, 0, -1)) {
    puts("An error occurred");
}
```

ps You should use the macros SEEK_SET,SEEK_CUR,SEEK_END in fseek rather than the -1

Comment: And to reinforce this, you should *always* check the return values from functions that can error so that you can report the error. Unless you really don't care about the results.

Comment: minor note, you shouldn't assume that `errno` is retained across library function calls. either use something like `printf("Error opening file: %s", strerror(errno));` or save the value of `errno` before calling anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use -1 for the third parameter of fseek? It should be any of SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR or SEEK_END.

As per your code, this should be SEEK_SET, that seeks to the beginning of the file, but using 0 as in your case leaves the pointer just at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 2):

You are opening you file in text mode (since you haven't specified and explicit `b` flag for `fopen`). For files opened in text mode the functionality of `fseek` is limited. The last parameter can only be `SEEK_SET` and nothing else. The position, if specified by a user-constructed value, must be `0` and nothing else.

You obviously satisfied the latter requirement, but what is that `-1` doing there is not clear.

> **7.19.9.2 The fseek function**
>   **4** For a text stream, either **offset** shall be
>   zero, or **offset** shall be a value
>   returned by an earlier successful call
>   to the **ftell** function on a stream
>   associated with the same file and
>   **whence** shall be **SEEK_SET**.

Answer (score 0):

`fseek()` returns 0 if it succeeds.

Comment: `fseek()` return the value 0 if successful; otherwise the value -1 is returned and the global variable `errno` is set to indicate the error.